# Unsorted Json file to data frame Rfv

Tags: json, r, dataframe, jsonlite

I'm trying to import a compressed json file in format bz2, and turn it into a data frame (link to file and dput example below). I'm somewhat successful using these lines of code

```
library(jsonlite)
out <- lapply(readLines("RC_2005-12.bz2"), fromJSON)
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(out), nrow = length(out), byrow = T))
```

`out` is a nested list of named entries. However, these named entries aren't in an order so columns in `df` become mix of different entries.
If we use the dput example below then in the first list *controversiality* is the first entry, while *utc_created* is the first entry in the second list. This causes the first column in `df` to look like:

```
X1
0
1134365725
```

This should of course be a column of two zeros corresponding to the *controversiality* of each sublist. How can I order/sort/regularize the sublists so the columns will match? Alternatively, how can I use the matched names as a condition when I convert the list into a df?

the full data file `RC_2005-12.bz2` is available at http://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/

First two sublists from `out`below:

```
 list(structure(list(controversiality = 0, body = "A look at Vietnam and Mexico exposes the myth of market liberalisation.", 
subreddit_id = "t5_6", link_id = "t3_17863", stickied = FALSE, 
subreddit = "reddit.com", score = 2, ups = 2, author_flair_css_class = NULL, 
created_utc = 1134365188, author_flair_text = NULL, author = "frjo", 
id = "c13", edited = FALSE, parent_id = "t3_17863", gilded = 0, 
distinguished = NULL, retrieved_on = 1473738411), .Names = c("controversiality", "body", "subreddit_id", "link_id", "stickied", "subreddit", "score", "ups", "author_flair_css_class", "created_utc", "author_flair_text", "author", "id", "edited", "parent_id", "gilded", "distinguished", "retrieved_on")), structure(list(created_utc = 1134365725, author_flair_css_class = NULL, score = 1, ups = 1, subreddit = "reddit.com", stickied = FALSE, link_id = "t3_17866", subreddit_id = "t5_6", controversiality = 0, body = "The site states \"What can I use it for? Meeting notes, Reports, technical specs Sign-up sheets, proposals and much more...\", just like any other new breeed of sites that want us to store everything we have on the web. And they even guarantee multiple levels of security and encryption etc. But what prevents these web site operators fom accessing and/or stealing Meeting notes, Reports, technical specs Sign-up sheets, proposals and much more, for competitive or personal gains...? I am pretty sure that most of them are honest, but what's there to prevent me from setting up a good useful site and stealing all your data? Call me paranoid - I am.", 
retrieved_on = 1473738411, distinguished = NULL, gilded = 0, 
id = "c14", edited = FALSE, parent_id = "t3_17866", author = "zse7zse", 
author_flair_text = NULL), .Names = c("created_utc", "author_flair_css_class", "score", "ups", "subreddit", "stickied", "link_id", "subreddit_id", controversiality", "body", "retrieved_on", "distinguished", "gilded", "id", "edited", "parent_id", "author", "author_flair_text" )))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `read_ndjson` function from **corpus** doesn't care what order the fields appear:

```
data <- corpus::read_ndjson(bzfile("RC_2005-12.bz2"))
```

---

**Unrelated problem that needs fixing**:

It looks like the person that made this file did it incorrectly. It was encoded in UTF-8 but they thought it was Latin-1. See, e.g. record 8:

```
data$body[8]
#> [1] "I donâ\u0080\u0099t know where they came up with this stuff, but Qube Web Search Client has taken the market by surprise. This is a cool concept thatâ\u0080\u0099s just beginning to blossom. You can save time by copying and pasting words and phrases."
```

Fix it by first undoing their conversion from what they thought was Latin-1 to UTF-8:

```
body <- iconv(data$body, "UTF-8", "Latin1")
```

Then set the correct encoding:

```
Encoding(body) <- "UTF-8"
```

Inspect the results:

```
body[8]
#> [1] "I don’t know where they came up with this stuff, but Qube Web Search Client has taken the market by surprise. This is a cool concept that’s just beginning to blossom. You can save time by copying and pasting words and phrases."
```

Make sure it's valid:

```
all(utf8::utf8_valid(body))
#> TRUE
```

Change the data back:

```
data$body <- body
```

The other fields in your data probably need the same.

Comment: watch out, it looks like whoever made this file encoded it incorrectly; e.g. the body from line 8: `"I don\u00e2\u0080\u0099t know where they`

Answer (score 1):

Your file seems to have an object per line. We could slightly modify your JSONs to make a single JSON array and let `jsonlite::fromJSON` do the dirty work. Something like:

```
require(jsonlite)
lines<-paste0("[",paste(readLines("RC_2005-12.bz2"),collapse=","),"]")
fromJSON(lines)
#'data.frame':  1075 obs. of  18 variables:
# $ controversiality      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#...
```

Comment: I don't get how you get from the `lines` object to a data frame. In my case `fromJSON(lines)` produces the same element as my lapply call above.

Comment: I get a `data.frame` as output of `fromJSON(lines)`. Don't know what the issue is. I have R 3.4.1 and  `jsonlite` version 1.5 and I'm on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.